# Link to iOS 10 Lock screen widget documentation?

Tags: ios

New in iOS 10 users can interact with iOS Push Notifications, such as respond to Messages and get mapping information... Can someone provide a link to the Apple documentation on how this is accomplished? I'd love to add this to my current app but can't find any information on how to build an actionable push notification.

Comment: **Note to close voters:** This is not a request for resource recommendations, but rather a plea for help finding a link to a specific piece of hard-to-find documentation. The stated reason for rejecting requests for resource recommendations is that they lead to many answers with different opinions. That doesn't apply here: any correct answer will point to essentially the same documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [iOS 10.0 What's New document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-DontLinkElementID_2), the framework you're interested in is `UserNotificationsUI.framework`. Googling that will take you to the [UserNotificationsUI page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui), including a link to the [`UNNotificationContentExtension` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension) which seems to be the right way to customize the UI for a notification.